# a nilpotent operator T is completely reducible

Tags: linear-algebra

prove if a nilpotent operator T is completely reducible, then $T=O_{V\rightarrow V}$

If T is nilpotent , its only eigenvalues are 0 (repeated roots).

(This is because the characteristic equation is $m^n =0$.Here n is the dimension of the vector space on which T operates)

If T is completely reducible , it has n linearly independent eigen vectors, say $ v_1, v_2,......v_n$ .

with respect to this basis , clearly T is the zero matrix.

Hence T acts as 0 on the entire vector space V (as $v_1, v_2,......v_n$ form a basis for V)

Thus $ T =0$.

would someone verify my answer. If anything wrong with it please corrected for me. Thank you

Comment: What is a completely reducible operator here? I heard something like that in Banach spaces.

Comment: Let $T$ be a linear operator on an finite-dimensional vector space $V$. The operator $T$ is said to be completely reducible if every $T-$ invariant subspace $U$ has a T-complement.

Comment: Thank you. Is it a standard result that a completely reducible operator on a $\;n-$ dimensional space has $\;n\;$ lin. independent eigenvectors (and is thus diagonalizable)?

Comment: would you please explain a bit more. Thank you

Comment: I just asked about the claim in your fifth line.

Comment: I am not really sure. But there is a Thm : let $V$ be a finite-dimensrioanl vector space and T a linear operator on V. Then T is diagonalizable if and only if T is completely reducible and $\mu_{T}(x)$ factors into linear factors. I would really be thankful  if you would clean up my proof.

Comment: Where did you take that theorem from? The truth is I know that any operator of finite dimensional space is diagonalizable iff its minimal polynomial factors into DIFFERENT linear factors, so somehow the completely reducible thing seems to cover the DIFFERENT that is lacking in your version, and I never heard of "completely reducible" in this framework.

Comment: I have taken it from Advanced Linear Algebra-Cooperstein page 136

Comment: Ok, I've read it (Google books) and it is as you say, but then I can't see where did you deduce that $\;T\;$ being comp. reducible $\;\implies\;$ it has $\;n\;$ different eigenvectors

Answer (score 0):

What I think can be done is the following: since $\;T\;$ is comp. reducible then by theorem 4.18 in Cooperstein's book its minimal polynomial factors into distinct irreducible factors. But as you say, since $\;x^n\;$ is its characteristic polynomial, the only possible irreducible factor here is the polynomial $\;x\;$, which of course means $\;T\;$ is the zero operator.